# Access this-object in a WINAPI callback

Tags: c++, winapi, lambda, callback

I want to set up a hook in a secondary thread, the thread object is an object member, so I decided to pass a lambda that captures `this` by reference as a call to the copy constructor would create yet another thread leading to infinite recursion.

```
MyClass() : thread_([this](){
    HHOOK kbdHook_LL = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, some_func_ptr, 0, 0);
    MSG msg;
    while(!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(kbdHook_LL);
    return 0;
}) {}
```

My problem is that I need `some_func_ptr` to know about the `this`-object as it also stores information needed for processing the event. But I cannot use a nested lambda to capture it, as only capture-less lambdas can be used as function pointers.

`some_func_ptr` should look like this

```
LRESULT CALLBACK some_func_ptr(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if(nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT pData = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
        switch(wParam) {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                //use `this` in some way
                break;
            case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                //etc.
                break;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I'm not that experienced in C++ yet, especially not in the C based kernel APIs, therefore I am not sure how to solve this.

Comment: It never makes sense to have more than a single callback for this hook.  So the function, as well as any members it uses, should be *static*.  Maybe having a static std::vector of objects that are interested in the callback can make sense.

Comment: I expected it to a an added static somewhere but I had no idea where. Thanks for the idea. I'll try it when I'm back at my PC.

Comment: because hook callback not receiver in parameters any your pointer - you and can not have `this` here easy and direct. so really it must be static or you need allocate "thunk" code - where will be stored pointer to your class and call(or jump) to member function